# why when I scroll tableview selected cells will show incorrect selected cells in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, swift4

I have a table view that user can select cells But this table view class is not table view controller so I used empty and fill image for non selected and selected cells in table view But the problem is that when I selected some cells and scroll down and when I scroll up again the cells that I selected will display non select But these cells are selected But what I see is that these cells are not selected ! 
**remember that I used will Display method too But the problem didn't solved**
here is my codes for that

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let filterSubTitleCell = self.filteringSubTitle.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filteringSubTitleCell", for: indexPath) as! filteringSubTitleCell

    filterSubTitleCell.selectionStyle = .none

    if listOfFilterJobs[lastIndex].selectedItem != nil{
        if listOfFilterJobs[lastIndex].selectedItem?.count != 0 {
            if (listOfFilterJobs[lastIndex].selectedItem?.contains(indexPath))!{
                filterSubTitleCell.checkImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkfill")
                filterSubTitleCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
             } else {
                filterSubTitleCell.checkImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkempty")
             }
         } else {
             filterSubTitleCell.checkImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkempty")
         }
     }else {
         filterSubTitleCell.checkImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkempty")
     }



    filterSubTitleCell.subTitle.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].title
    filterSubTitleCell.subTitle?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    filterSubTitleCell.subTitle?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5


    return filterSubTitleCell
}
```